# multiple search index spring data solr showcase

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data

how do i can search multiple index content in spring data solr showcase?
just now i only can search "name".
for example how do i can search "companyNo"?.
thanks in advance

sample xml of indexed in solr:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<add>
    <doc>
    <field name="id">1051879H_15082014_00003457</field>
    <field name="name">BEST MEGALINK SDN. BHD.</field>
    <field name="entityName"></field>
    <field name="companyNo">1051879-H</field>
    <field name="noticeType">RMAT_N_C</field>
    <field name="noticeDate">15/08/2014</field>
    <field name="repNames"></field>
    <field name="repNames"></field>
    <field name="repNames"></field>
    <field name="repICs"></field>
    <field name="repICs"></field>
    <field name="repICs"></field>
    <field name="format">PDF</field>
    <field name="folder">15082014</field>
    <field name="pages">2</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other fields which need to be searched, needs to be added as part of [schema.xml](http://www.solrtutorial.com/schema-xml.html).

For example, the fields like the following needs to be added as part schema.xml:

```
<field name="entityName" type="text_string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="companyNo" type="text_string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="noticeType" type="text_string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: i already add in schema. if i using http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ or http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/browse, i can easily search all content that i indexed. but when i try to search using sping-data-solr-showcase it can't find. it only can search for index "name" only. it that something i miss out?